# Shiny fileInput() does not react to multiple files selection

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently having an issue on a complex shinyApp I am building, and since I did not find an answer elsewhere, I come up to ask SO community.
I warn you that my app is quite complex, with nested modules call. I did try to reproduce the problem to a smaller scale but it did work at smaller scales. So I suspect the bug to be a mistake - or Shiny misunderstanding - from me.
As I could not give a reproducible example, I invite anyone who wants to help to go check the [git](https://github.com/earnaud/MetaShARK/tree/dev) (This is the dev branch).

## Details of the problem

The problem is quite silly but still is there: in `modules/EMLAL/EMLAL_selectDP.R`, I want to use a `fileInput()` function. It is written as:

```r
fileInput(ns("data.files.browse"), 
          "Select your data files (make sure they are in the same directory)",
          TRUE)
```

Thus, it is expected to allow multiple files input, and display them below. But when I try the app, I click on the "Browse" button, select my files in the opening window and ... nothing happens. The "upload" bar does not display, and the reactives in the server can't work. Check [this video](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/earnaud/MetaShARK/dev/fileInput_bug.ogv) to see a screenshot of the issue.

## Computer features

OS (from `lsb_release -a`):

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
```

R version:

```r
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          6.0                         
year           2019                        
month          04                          
day            26                          
svn rev        76424                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
nickname       Planting of a Tree
```

Shiny version:

```r
[1] `1.3.2`
```

I have no clues about whether this is a mistake from my part, a shiny issue or my computer which is not configured properly.

By advance, thanks to those who will take some time to help me.

Comment: You should try to isolate the problem as much as possible. I don't think anybody has the time to go through your whole repo.

Comment: Thansk you for your advice. I know my demand is awful, but as I said, I don't succeed to reproduce the error. The best I can do is to show the error.